# How do I delete duplicate contacts on device with Google Contacts (Android)?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I am using [Google Contacts app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts) on my Android phone. I have hundreds of contacts stored on device, which I do not want to store in my Google account. After importing some contacts, I now have many duplicate contacts. How do I remove the duplicates, using Google Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the [Google Contacts app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts) does *not* offer a way to easily remove duplicates from the contacts stored only on the device. There are apps available on the Google Play store that promise to do this, but none of them are reputable, so if you don't want to share your contacts online, you may not want to use these apps.

If you want to remove duplicates from contacts that are stored online in your Google accounts, you can follow [these instructions](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/7078226?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid):

> - On your Android phone or tablet, open the Contacts app .
> - At the top left, tap Menu and then "Merge and fix".
> - Tap "Merge duplicates". If you don’t get this option, you don’t have any contacts that can be merged.

You can move the contacts stored on your device to your Google account, if you want. When I tried this, Google Contacts only found a couple of the duplicate contacts at first, it did not find the majority of them. But a day later, the Google Contacts app found all of them.